# Bootstrap Tabs with Google Map API not completely loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I am trying to use the Google Maps API inside of a Bootstrap tab. When the map is in the first tab it loads properly, but I have to move it to the second tab because of UI considerations. When I do that, the map doesn't complete it's loading. I am using a class called "appt-lo" to trigger the first tab to show active. If I move that class to the second tab, my map shows, otherwise, it does not. If you guys could maybe give me some ideas or point me in the right direction, I would deeply appreciate it.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/madjaybird/pen/YxJErx?editors=1000

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.madjaybird.com/Codepen/main.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.madjaybird.com/Codepen/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Inline Online - The Online Appointment Scheduler for NM MVD</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/styles/main.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Palanquin:400,300,100,200,500,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body class="intro wizard">
  <div id="header" role="banner">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg bg-dark fixed-top justify-content-between">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://mvd.newmexico.gov"><span>MVD</span> NEW MEXICO</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-auto d-none d-flex">
          <li class="nav-item pr-2 pt-2" id="time">15:00<span> minutes</span></li>
          <li class="nav-item pr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="admin-calendar-month-0817.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Admin Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item pr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="admin-help.html"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> Help</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item pr-2"><a class="nav-link" href="admin-signin.html"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-6">
      <div class=" card wizard-card">
        <div class="wizard-header">
          <h3>
            <b>MAKE</b> YOUR APPOINTMENT<br>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <ul class="justify-content-around nav nav-tabs nav-fill setup-panel">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn-default nav-link link appt-lo" href="#step-1">Appointment Type</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn-default nav-link link" href="#step-2">Appointment Location</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn-default nav-link link" href="#step-3">Date &amp; Time</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn-default nav-link link" href="#step-4">Add Appointment</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="btn-default nav-link link" href="#step-5">Customer Information</a></li>
        </ul>

        <form role="form" action="" method="post">


          <!-- Step 1: Appointment Type -->
          <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
            <div class="col mt-4">
              <div class="row mx-1 mb-4">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <h4 class="info-text"> Select Your Appointment Type </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="btn-group float-right" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prevBtn"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning nextBtn">Next <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr class="my-2">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                <div class="cards p-2">
                  <div class="card1 has-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-card select">
                      <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="jobb" value="Code">
                        <div class="icon">
                          <i class="fas fa-id-card"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class="mt-2">First Time <br>Driver's License</h6>
                        <small class="text-center"><a href="http://www.mvd.newmexico.gov/apply-for-new-driver-s-license.aspx" target="_blank">Required Documents</a></small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cards p-2">
                  <div class="has-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-card select">
                      <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="jobb" value="Code">
                        <div class="icon">
                          <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class="mt-2">First TIme Title</h6>
                        <small class="text-center"><a href="http://www.mvd.newmexico.gov/how-to-title-a-vehicle.aspx#" target="_blank">Required Documents</a></small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cards p-2">
                  <div class="has-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-card select">
                      <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="jobb" value="Code">
                        <div class="icon">
                          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class="mt-2">VIN Inspection</h6>
                        <small class="text-center"><a href="http://www.mvd.newmexico.gov/register-your-vehicle.aspx" target="_blank">Required Documents</a></small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                <div class="cards p-2">
                  <div class="has-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-card select">
                      <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="jobb" value="Code">
                        <div class="icon">
                          <i class="fas fa-road"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class="mt-2">Road Test</h6>
                        <small class="text-center"><a href="http://www.mvd.newmexico.gov/apply-for-new-driver-s-license.aspx" target="_blank">Required Documents</a></small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cards p-2">
                  <div class="has-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-card select">
                      <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="jobb" value="Code">
                        <div class="icon">
                          <i class="fa fa-motorcycle"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class="mt-2">Motorcycle <br>Road Test</h6>
                        <small class="text-center"><a href="http://www.mvd.newmexico.gov/apply-for-new-driver-s-license.aspx" target="_blank">Required Documents</a></small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cards p-2">
                  <div class="has-overlay">
                    <div class="overlay-card select">
                      <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="jobb" value="Code">
                        <div class="icon">
                          <i class="fas fa-shield-alt"></i>
                        </div>
                        <h6 class="mt-2">Fingerprinting</h6>
                        <small class="text-center"><a href="http://www.dps.state.nm.us/index.php/fingerprint-information/" target="_blank">Required Documents</a></small>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr>
              <div class="row mx-1 mb-4">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <h4 class="info-text"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="btn-group float-right" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prevBtn"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning nextBtn">Next <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Step 2: Location -->
          <div class="row justify-content-center setup-content" id="step-2">
            <div class="col text-center mt-4">
              <div class="row mx-1 mb-4">
                <div class="col-6">
                  <img src="dist/images/MVDlogo.png" alt="MVD NM logo" class="step2" width="80">
                  <h4 class="info-text"> Find an MVD Field Office near you.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <div class="btn-group float-right" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default prevBtn"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning nextBtn">Next <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="row my-4 mx-4">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <div class="thumbnail map-wrapper">
                    <div id="map-canvas">
                      <div id="map">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <div>
                    <div id="maps">
                      <p>To find an MVD Service Provider near you, enter your City or ZIP Code.</p>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only">City/ZIP Code</label>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="location text-left">
                      <h5><strong>Select Location:</strong></h5>
                      <div class="address"><a href="#">Santa Fe</a></div>
                      <div>2546 Camino Entrada</div>
                      <div>Santa Fe, NM 87507</div>
                      <div>505-476-1599</div>
                      <div> Monday - Friday 8am - 4pm</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <hr>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-warning nextBtn btn-lg float-right" type="button">Next <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Step 3: Date & Time  -->
          <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
            <div class="col mt-4">
              <div class="row mx-1 mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-lg float-left" type="button"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <h4 class="info-text"> Select Date &amp; Time </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <button class="btn btn-warning nextBtn btn-lg float-right" type="button">Next <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <div class="location text-center">
                    <div class="address">Santa Fe</div>
                    <div>2546 Camino Entrada Santa Fe, NM 87507 </div>
                    <div>505-476-1599 Monday - Friday 8am - 4pm</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr class="mb-0">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm">
                  <p class="text-center">Please select the date and the time for your appointment.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row mx-4">
                <div class="col-sm mt-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Date of Appointment: </label>
                    <input class="form-control date-picker" type="date" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm block_list_words mt-2">
                  <label class="control-label">Time of Appointment: </label>
                  <ul id="handle-1" class="list-unstyled">
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 9:00 am<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 9:30 am<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 10:00 am<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 10:30 am<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 11:00 am<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 11:30 am<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 12:00 pm<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 12:30 pm<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 1:00 pm<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 1:30 pm<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 2:00 pm<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 3:00 pm<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 3:30 pm<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 4:00 pm<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="datetime">
                      <span class="drag-handle"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></span> 4:30 pm<span class="float-right sortable-links"></span>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-default prevBtn btn-lg float-left" type="button"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-warning nextBtn btn-lg float-right" type="button">Next <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Step 4: Add Appointment -->
          <div class="row setup-content" id="step-4">
            <div class="col mt-4">
              <div class="row mx-1 mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                  <button class="btn btn-default prevBtn btn-lg float-left" type="button"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <h4 class="info-text"> Make Another Appointment </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <button class="btn btn-warning nextBtn btn-lg float-right" type="button">Next <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row justify-content-center ml-0 mt-4">
                <div class="col text-center">
                  <p class="lead">Would you like to make another appointment?</p>
                  <p class=" mb-4"> If so, click the <b>MAKE ANOTHER APPOINTMENT</b> button below. If not, click <b>NEXT</b>.</p>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="window.location.href='ui-wizard.html'">Make Another Appointment</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-default prevBtn btn-lg float-left" type="button"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-warning nextBtn btn-lg float-right" type="button">Next <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Step 5: Customer Information -->
          <div class="row setup-content" id="step-5">
            <div class="col mt-4">
              <div class="row mx-1 mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                  <button class="btn btn-default prevBtn btn-lg float-left" type="button"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <h4 class="info-text"> Enter Your Information </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary nextBtn btn-lg float-right" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='ui-review.html'">Finish <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mx-4">
                <form class="container" id="needs-validation" novalidate>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="text-red">*</span>
                        <label for="firstName"> First Name</label>
                        <input name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a first name.
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="text-red">*</span>
                        <label for="lastName"> Last Name</label>
                        <input name="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="text-red">*</span>
                        <label> Email</label>
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="text-red">*</span>
                        <label> Phone </label>
                        <input name="phone" type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Driver's License Number</label>
                        <input name="dln" type="text" class="form-control" id="dln" placeholder="Driver's License Number">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <hr>
                <button class="btn btn-default prevBtn btn-lg float-left" type="button"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary nextBtn btn-lg float-right" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='ui-review.html'">Finish <i class="fal fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer mt-5">
      <a href="#"><img src="dist/images/inlineonline-logo.png" alt="In Line Online logo" width="250"></a>
      <p> Copyright &copy; 2017 State of New Mexico</p>
    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCDaUcFwmFZosg6lIjUQFolSsqp_Zd9GCw&callback=initMap"></script>
    <!-- / SCRIPTS -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So your question is why doesn't is the google map loaded when you click next and if you click on it you see the map. But their aren't any markers on it?

Comment: Yes, the solution below fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone! You rock! I really appreciate the help! It totally worked!

Comment: You just need to approve his answer so we now it is solved and that his answer can help other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` inside `allNextBtn.click`'s callback function within a `setTimeout` seems to render the map completely on tab change.

```
//Next Button script
      allNextBtn.click(function () {
       //trigger map resize on tab select
        setTimeout(function(){
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');           
        },10)
        var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          nextStepWizard = $('ul.setup-panel li a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
          curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
          isValid = true;

        $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
        for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
          if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
            isValid = false;
            $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          }
        }

        if (isValid)
          nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
      });
```

Codepen url https://codepen.io/azs06/pen/RZeMWV?editors=0010

Comment: great, I just tried adding resize on next click and noticed it solved the issue, that's why I posted the solution. It's great that you found better way to solve this.